# What is a comprehensive alternative set of books that can substitute the three volume set of Kendall's books?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

What is a comprehensive alternative set of books that can substitute the three volume set of Kendall's advanced statistics books?

I. Distribution Theory

IIA. Classical Inference & the Linear Model

IIB. Bayesian Inference

I don't want to borrow or buy too many books!

Comment: I suspect any effort to recreate the contents of these three volumes would require far more than three volumes and likely be *more* expensive.  Perhaps the count of the number of books should not be the criterion one uses to select them, though. Shouldn't their contents matter far more?

Comment: @whuber I mean a different set of books ...

Comment: Unless you identify what you're prepared to lose that's in the books, I don't see how this is answerable. The volumes are very information-dense, I don't see any reasonable way of covering the same material in similar depth more briefly. Similarly when you say "a different set of books", in what ways should the different set of books differ from some edition of Kendall (et al)? What differences are acceptable and what differences are not?